# Запятая при причастном обороте

Tags: причастный-оборот

Помогите переделать предложение, по-моему, оно построено неправильно.

> В соответствии с Указом был утвержден
> план мероприятий, проходивших в
> учреждениях культуры муниципального
> района.

И слово *указ*, думаю, надо писать с маленькой буквы, ведь в этом предложении нет официального названия указа. (В начале статьи речь идет об Указе Путина "О проведении в РФ Года культуры".)

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Может, примерно так?

*В соответствии с этим указом в  [таком-то] районе был разработан и утвержден план проведения в учреждениях культуры района необходимых мероприятий в рамках Года культуры.*

Или так:

*В соответствии с указом был утвержден план мероприятий, **проведённых впоследствии**  в учреждениях культуры муниципального района.*

Comment: Спасибо, мне нравится Ваш первый вариант,

Comment: план проведения - чего?<....>,  здесь требуется дополнение, а не обстоятельство.

Answer (score 1):

А чем вам не нравится  предложение? И запятая у вас стоит на месте. Слово "Указ'' действительно, надо со строчной писать.

Возможно так: ... был разработан план предстоящих мероприятий в учреждениях  культуры муниципального района.

Comment: Не нравиться здесь может причастие прошедшего времени: утвердили план якобы уже проходивших мероприятий.

Comment: Вот и я об этом.